# Compare Student ID in multiple row and get the desired output

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe like this

| Student ID | Subject | Current class | assessment class | prev cls | current cls | next cls |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | English | Class 2 | Class 2 | -- | Class2 Pass | -- |
| 101 | English | Class2 | Class3 | -- | -- | Class3 Pass |
| 101 | Mathematics | Class 2 | Class 2 | -- | Class 2 fail | -- |
| 101 | Mathematics | Class 2 | Class 1 | Class 1 fail | -- | -- |
| 102 | English | Class 2 | Class 2 | -- | Class2 Pass | -- |
| 102 | English | Class 2 | Class 3 | -- | -- | Class 3 Fail |
| 102 | Mathematics | Class2 | Class2 | -- | Class2 fail | -- |
| 102 | Mathematics | Class2 | Class1 | Class1 Pass | -- | -- |

I want a output like this

| Student ID | Subject | Current class | Expert lvl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | English | Class2 | class3 pass |
| 101 | Mathematics | Class 2 | class 1 fail |
| 102 | English | Class2 | class2 pass |
| 102 | Mathematics | Class 2 | class 1 pass |

The condition are a student who belongs to class-2 takes a quiz of class-2

- If gets pass he/she goes one level up and tries class-3 quiz.
- If he/she passes the class-3 quiz his/her expertise level is fixed as class-3 in that subject.
- If he/she fails class-3 quiz his/her expert level is fixed as class-2 (only If he/she has passed class-2 quiz) otherwise his/her expert level is fixed as class-1 either he passes or fails class-1.

How do I write in python to get this kind of data frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step would be to group all cls in a single column (not sure if more than one cls column can be different than `--` but this would be handled here) and group by `Student ID` and `Subject`:

```
df['cls'] = df[['prev cls', 'current cls', 'next cls']].agg(lambda x: [i for i in x if i!='--'], axis=1)
df = df.groupby(['Student ID', 'Subject'], as_index=False).agg({'Current class': 'last', 'cls': 'sum'})
```

This gives you the df:

```
   Student ID      Subject Current class                           cls
0         101      English        Class2    [Class2 Pass, Class3 Pass]
1         101  Mathematics       Class 2  [Class 2 fail, Class 1 fail]
2         102      English       Class 2   [Class2 Pass, Class 3 Fail]
3         102  Mathematics        Class2    [Class2 fail, Class1 Pass]
```

From there you can transform the `cls` column with a function that will get the max passed level or the lowest failed level:

```
import re
def get_expert_lvl(tests: list):
    passed = [x for x in tests if 'pass' in x.lower()]
    if passed:
        return max(passed, key=lambda x: int(re.search(r'\d+', x).group()))
    else:
        return min(tests, key=lambda x: int(re.search(r'\d+', x).group()))

df['Expert lvl'] = df['cls'].transform(get_expert_lvl)
df.drop('cls', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

You end up with:

```
   Student ID      Subject Current class    Expert lvl
0         101      English        Class2   Class3 Pass
1         101  Mathematics       Class 2  Class 1 fail
2         102      English       Class 2   Class2 Pass
3         102  Mathematics        Class2   Class1 Pass
```